I'm having trouble building a multi-user video chat program with WebRTC and SignalR
I wrote a very simple sample for user communication, but the problem is that when I try to connect more than two people to it, the program doesn't work correctly, and it doesn't show the streams of other participants for the third person. I'll post the written code here.
js Code:
const videoGrid = document.querySelector("[video-grid]");

let video = null;
let roomId = "";
let localStream = null;
let userId = null;

let peers = [];


const srConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/chatHub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

srConnection.onclose(start);


srConnection.on("user-Connected",
    (uid, connectedIds) => {
        userId = userId === null ? uid : userId;
        console.log("user connected ", connectedIds);
        for (var i = 0; i < connectedIds.length; i++) {
            if (typeof (peers[connectedIds[i]]) === "undefined")
                peers[connectedIds[i]] = createPeerConnection();
        }

    });




srConnection.on("UserLeft",
    (id, ids) => {

        console.log("user Left", id, "RoomParticipants", ids);
    });

async function start() {
    try {
        await srConnection.start();

        InitVideoStream();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};

start();


const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata",
        () => {
            video.play();
        });
    videoGrid.appendChild(video);
}

var InitVideoStream = () => {



    if (!navigator.mediaDevices?.enumerateDevices) {
        console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
    } else {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .enumerateDevices()
            .then((devices) => {
                devices.forEach((device) => {
                    if (device.kind === "audioinput") {
                        $("#audioSource").append(`<option value="${device.deviceId}">${device.label}</option>`)
                    } else if (device.kind === "videoinput") {
                        $("#videoSource").append(`<option value="${device.deviceId}">${device.label}<</option>`)
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
            });
    }

}


async function sourcesSelected() {
    roomId = $("#roomId").val();
    if (roomId === "") {
        alert("Insert a Room Id");
        return;
    }
    if ($("#videoSource").val() === "0") {
        alert("Select a Video Device");
        return;
    }
    if ($("#audioSource").val() === "0") {
        alert("Select a Audio Device");
        return;
    }

    let audioSource = $("#audioSource").val();
    let videoSource = $("#videoSource").val();
    const constraints = {
        audio: { deviceId: audioSource },
        video: { deviceId: videoSource },
    };

    if (!navigator.mediaDevices?.getUserMedia) {
        video.src = "fallbackvideo.webm";
    }
    else {
        await srConnection.invoke("JoinRoom", roomId);

        let rtcConnection = peers[userId];
    
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then(function (stream) {

                localStream = stream;
                video = document.createElement('video');
                video.muted = true;
                addVideoStream(video, stream);


                Object.keys(peers).forEach(peerId => {
                    if (peers[peerId].addStream) {
                        peers[peerId].addStream(localStream);
                    }
                });


            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
            });


    }
}



srConnection.on("Receive", (data, id) => {

    if (userId === id) return
    var message = JSON.parse(data);

    if (message.sdp) {
        if (message.sdp.type == 'offer') {

            let rtcConnection = peers[id];
            rtcConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp))
                .then(function () {
                    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
                })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    localStream = stream;
                    video = document.createElement('video');
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    rtcConnection.addStream(localStream);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    return rtcConnection.createAnswer();
                })
                .then(function (answer) {
                    return rtcConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    srConnection.invoke("Send", JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': rtcConnection.localDescription }), roomId, userId)
                });
        }
        else if (message.sdp.type == 'answer') {
                rtcConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp));
        }
    } else if (message.candidate) {
        rtcConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
    }
});

function createPeerConnection() {
    rtcConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(null);

    rtcConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = function () {
        console.log('ICE State Change:', rtcConnection.iceConnectionState);
    };
    rtcConnection.onsignalingstatechange = function () {
        console.log('Signaling State Change:', rtcConnection.signalingState);
    };

    rtcConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (event.candidate) {
            srConnection.invoke("Send", JSON.stringify({ "candidate": event.candidate }), roomId, userId);
        }
    }

    rtcConnection.onaddstream = function (event) {
        const userVideo = document.createElement("video");
        userVideo.autoplay = true;
        userVideo.playsInline = true;
        addVideoStream(userVideo, event.stream);
    }

    rtcConnection.onnegotiationneeded = function () {
        rtcConnection.createOffer()
            .then(function (offer) {
                return rtcConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            })
            .then(function () {
                srConnection.invoke("Send", JSON.stringify({ "sdp": rtcConnection.localDescription }), roomId, userId);
            });
    }

    return rtcConnection;
}

I've implemented the signaling server with SignalR, and it's working fine. However, to provide sufficient context, I'll post it for you.
hub:
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, List<string>> RoomParticipants = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> ConnectedUserList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public async Task JoinRoom(string roomId)
        {
            var userId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomId);
            ConnectedUserList.Add(Context.ConnectionId, userId);

            if (!RoomParticipants.ContainsKey(roomId))
                RoomParticipants[roomId] = new List<string>();

            RoomParticipants[roomId].Add(userId);
            await Clients.Group(roomId).SendAsync("user-connected", userId, RoomParticipants[roomId]);
        }
        private string GetRoomNameByUser(string userId)
        {
            foreach (var room in RoomParticipants)
            {
                if (room.Value.Contains(userId))
                {
                    return room.Key;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private async Task<bool> LeaveRoomByUser(string roomName, string userId)
        {
            await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
            ConnectedUserList.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
            if (RoomParticipants.ContainsKey(roomName))
            {
                RoomParticipants[roomName].Remove(userId);
                if (RoomParticipants[roomName].Count == 0)
                {
                    RoomParticipants.Remove(roomName);
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public async override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            if (ConnectedUserList.ContainsKey(Context.ConnectionId))
            {
                var userId = ConnectedUserList[Context.ConnectionId];
                var roomName = GetRoomNameByUser(userId);
                if (await LeaveRoomByUser(roomName, userId))
                    await Clients.Group(roomName).SendAsync("UserLeft", userId, RoomParticipants[roomName]);

            }
        }

        public async Task LeaveRoom(string roomName, string userId)
        {
            if (await LeaveRoomByUser(roomName, userId))
                await Clients.Group(roomName).SendAsync("UserLeft", userId, RoomParticipants[roomName]);

        }


        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Context.ConnectionId} connected");
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }


html:
<input type="text" id="roomId" placeholder="Enter room Id" />
<br />
<select name="videoSource" id="videoSource">
    <option value="0">Select Video Source...</option>
</select>

<select name="audioSource" id="audioSource">
    <option value="0">Select audio Source...</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Start Video Stream" onclick="sourcesSelected();return;" />
<br />
<div video-grid>

</div>

I am trying to write a multiple chat app with rooms, but it doesn't work correctly.

any errors in the browser developer console? What troubleshooting have you attempted?

Yes, when I try to add the third user, it displays these errors in the console:
For the first user:
"Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable"
For the console of the second user and the third user:
"Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local offer sdp: The order of m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous offer/answer"
